# How to convert a image file loaded in memory to a ID2D1Bitmap in C++

Tags: c++, windows, direct2d, imaging

I'm trying to convert a image file (a png, but could be anything) that I just extracted into memory from a compressed file to a ID2D1Bitmap to draw using Direct 2D. I tried to look for some documentation, but I can only find methods that receive "const char* path" or ask me width and height of my image, that I can't know before-hand.
Searching on google for it got me nowhere.

The file is raw in memory, and I would like to avoid to extract images to the hdd into a temporary file just to read their data from there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use WIC to load it from an `IWICStream` and then use `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` to get your `ID2D1Bitmap` - there are examples on MSDN so I'm surprised you haven't found anything.

Comment: You have to first decode the image (for example using WIC) to raw RGB32 pixel data (this can be done in the memory), then you can use CreateBitmap() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj841129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You should pass the pointer to the decoded image to srcData parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have the HBITMAP handle, you can do this:

1. The the size of your image using: `::GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpSizeInfo);`
2. fill a BITMAPINFO like this:

   `memset(&bmpData, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
   bmpData.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmpData.bmiHeader);
   bmpData.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bmpSizeInfo.bmHeight;
   bmpData.bmiHeader.biWidth = bmpSizeInfo.bmWidth;
   bmpData.bmiHeader.biPlanes = bmpSizeInfo.bmPlanes;
   bmpData.bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmpSizeInfo.bmBitsPixel;`
3. create enough heap memory to hold the data for your bitmap:

   `pBuff = new char[bmpSizeInfo.bmWidth * bmpSizeInfo.bmHeight * 4];`
4. Get the bitmap data like this:

   `::GetDIBits(hDc, hBmp, 0, bmpSizeInfo.bmHeight, (void*)pBuff, &bmpData, DIB_RGB_COLORS);`
5. Create a `D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES` and fill it like this:

   `bmpPorp.dpiX = 0.0f;
   bmpPorp.dpiY = 0.0f;
   bmpPorp.pixelFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
   bmpPorp.pixelFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;`
6. Using your render target turn the data into ID2D1Bitmap

   `pRT->CreateBitmap(bmpSize, pBuff, 4 * bmpSizeInfo.bmWidth, bmpPorp, &pBmpFromH);`

Hope this can help.

Sam

Comment: Great, This is what I was looking for. For a long time beating my head around the keyboard.

Comment: @Ram Don't forget to delete the buffer created in heap (**pBuff**) like `delete[] pBuff;`

Comment: So to just creating a bitmap in memory and rendering it with Direct2D does not open the can of WIC-Worms, right?! :)

Comment: @BitTickler You are correct, this method directly transforms the image from GDI's HBITMAP to ID2D1Bitmap. No WIC is involved.